Flutter: best way to load multiple assets using just_audio package
I have some numbers to play from 0.mp3 to 46.mp3 so I initialise them like this:
static final AudioPlayer _numbers = AudioPlayer();

for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
      await _numbers.setAsset('assets/audio/numbers/$i.mp3');
    }

The problem is that it takes too much to load them. Using audioplayers was much faster (but I had to change to this package for other reasons.
Is it safe to remove the await and set a new asset before the previous one is loaded?

Why are you setting them all in a loop? There's no point in doing that. You should only set the single asset the moment you want to play it

I was setting up all my files as soon as I was loading the app. My app shows a timer and reproduces the number sound so I need to have all of them loaded before playing the sound, just in case it takes time to load

I don't think this does that. This doesn't do any setting up. It doesn't speed up playing the sound after. At least I wouldn't think so. You could just leave out the loop I think

Then I guess I will move back to the other package since I can't sacrifice any milliseconds when playing the sounds. Thanks

Try this:
  AudioPlayer? _player;

  Future<void> initPlayer() async {
    try {
      if (_player != null) {
        await _player?.dispose();
      }
      _player = AudioPlayer();
    } catch (e, stack) {
      log('error: $e, stack: $stack');
    }
  }

  Future<void> loadPlaylist() async {
    try {
      final _playlist = <AudioSource>[];
      for (int i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
      _playlist.add(
        AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse('asset:///audio/numbers/$i.mp3')),
      );
    }
      final _source = ConcatenatingAudioSource(
        children: _playlist,
        useLazyPreparation: false,
      );
      await _player?.setAudioSource(_source);
    } catch (e, stack) {
      log('error: $e, stack: $stack');
    }
  }

and then when you need to start:
await initPlayer();
await loadPlaylist();


what is _source ?

my bad. it is just instance of ConcatenatingAudioSource
